# Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am just trying to show user data after hitting the API using Retrofit. my api response is:
`{"password":"111222333","name":"test name","email":"testem@gmail.com","username":"test1","customer_id":"201060","phone":"0196789"}`

but unfortunately, I am getting "Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $" error.

I am totally stuck to show my json response. trying it for last two days.

**My User.java class:**

```
public class User {
  @SerializedName("name")
  @Expose
  private String name;
  @SerializedName("email")
  @Expose
  private String email;
  @SerializedName("username")
  @Expose
  private String username;
  @SerializedName("customer_id")
  @Expose
  private String customerId;
  @SerializedName("phone")
  @Expose
  private String phone;
  @SerializedName("password")
  @Expose
  private String password;
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }
  public String getEmail() {
    return email;
  }
  public String getUsername() {
    return username;
  }
  public String getCustomerId() {
    return customerId;
  }
  public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
  }
  public String getPassword() {
    return password;
  }
}
```

**My Login class:**

````
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://us-central1-gmx-notification.cloudfunctions.net/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
        all_api = retrofit.create(allApi.class);
private void getUserDetails(String userName,String passWord){
        Call<User> call = all_api.getUserDetails(userName,passWord);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
                if(!response.isSuccessful()){
                    Log.d(response.body());
                }
                else{
                    User user = response.body();
                    String content = "";
                    content+= "Name: "+user.getName()+"\n";
                    content+= "Email: "+user.getEmail()+"\n";
                    content+= "Customer ID: "+user.getCustomerId()+"\n";
                    content+= "Phone: "+user.getPhone()+"\n";
                    Log.d(content);
              }
});
}```
````

Comment: show us your object class

Comment: use this api response to create your model class. you can easily create your model class on http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org . then i think your problem will be resolved.

Comment: Which language you used kotlin or java? and share your API endpoint.

Comment: The error likely says that JSON you showed is not what you receive from the server. Check the actual server response

Comment: actually.. I test my api endpoint with Postman and it's just fine json response. {
    "password": "111222333",
    "name": "test name",
    "email": "testem@gmail.com",
    "username": "test1",
    "customer_id": "201060",
    "phone": "0196789"
}

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are trying to parse "String" instead of "Response Model" in your last call.

This issue will fix if you create a response model object like below:

```
data class UserInfo(
    val password: String? = null,
    val phone: String? = null,
    val name: String? = null,
    val customerId: String? = null,
    val email: String? = null,
    val username: String? = null
)
```

And pass this object in GET method of your interface like below:

```
@GET
fun getUserInfo() : Observable<UserInfo>
```

Let me know if you need some more detail.

Answer (score 0):

the error is due to the reason that you are trying to cast String input received from API response into Object. as in your response, all the keys are of string type so make sure the data type of all the variables in your bean/POJO class must be String.